# Dimensão da imagem renderizada pelo html2canvas

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

Eu tenho um script que cria uma imagem de uma `div` utilizando html2canvas e gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de alterar o `whidth` e o `height` dessa imagem.

```
<div id="MinhaDiv">Conteúdo a ser renderizado</div>
<input id="Gerador" type="button" value="Gerar Imagem"/>
<div id="IMGfinal" ></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var element = $("#MinhaDiv"); 

        $("#Gerador").on('click', function () {
            html2canvas(element, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $("#IMGfinal").append(canvas);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [documentação do html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration) oferece opções de configuração extras como `width` e `height`, que podem ser declaradas na própria função:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var element = $("#MinhaDiv"); 

    $("#Gerador").on('click', function () {
        html2canvas(element, { width: 500, height: 500,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $("#IMGfinal").append(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Valeu, me ajudou muito. Eu estava usando as propriedades de maneira errada, mas agora tudo funciona top;

Answer (score -3):

pode passar dentro da div o style pode funcionar

```
<div id="MinhaDiv" style="width: 1080; height: 240; >Conteúdo a ser renderizado</div>
```